# Indefinite Integration of complex function

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to integrate

$$ \int \frac{a^{x} (x+1)}{(x-1)^2}dx$$

I tried different substitutions but didn't achieved any thing

Please help

Comment: Are you sure it's Capital x, I.e. "X" in the numerator, or is it '$x$'?

Comment: Both are same this is a typo @JaideepKhare

Comment: The antiderivative doesn't exist in terms of the elementary functions but you  can write it in terms of the exponential integral $\mathrm{Ei}(x) := -\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}} t \mathrm dt$ (see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+a%5Ex(x%2B1)%2F(x-1)%5E2)

Comment: Usually complex integrals are defined in terms of a contour around the poles of the analytic function. In your case there is a pole at $x=1$. The residue of $\frac{a^x (x+1)}{(x-1)^2} $ at $x=1$ is $2a(\log{a} + 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

So as @George Coote's points out, the integral only can be expressed in closed-form in terms of the non-elementary function known as the [Exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $\text{Ei}(x)$. Defined as
$$\text{Ei}(x) = - \int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \, dt,$$
we will make use of the following indefinite form
$$\int \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \, dx = \text{Ei}(-t) + C.\tag1$$

Let
$$I = \int \frac{a^x (x + 1)}{(x - 1)^2} \, dx, \quad a > 0, a \neq 1.$$
Setting $x = 1 - t/\ln a, dx = - dt/\ln a$, after simplifying we have
\begin{align*}
I &= -a \int \frac{e^{-t} (2 \ln a - t)}{t^2} \, dt\\
&= a \int \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \, dt - 2a \ln a \int \frac{e^{-t}}{t^2} \, dt\\
&= a \int \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \, dt + 2a \ln a \frac{e^{-t}}{t} + 2a \ln a \int \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \, dt \quad \text{(by parts)}\\
&= 2a \ln a \frac{e^{-t}}{t} + a(1 + 2 \ln a) \int \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \, dt\\
&= 2a \ln a \frac{e^{-t}}{t} + a(1 + 2 \ln a) \text{Ei}(-t) + C,
\end{align*}
where use of the (1) has been made. Back substituting for $x$ one finds
$$\int \frac{a^x (x + 1)}{(x - 1)^2} \, dx = a(1 + 2 \ln a) \text{Ei}[(x - 1) \ln a] - \frac{2a^x}{x - 1} + C.$$

For the case when $a = 1$, the integral reduces to
$$I = \int \frac{x + 1}{(x - 1)^2} \, dx = \ln |x - 1| - \frac{2}{x - 1} + C,$$
a result that can readily found on applying a substitution of $u = x - 1$.

So in summary
$$\int \frac{a^x (x + 1)}{(x - 1)^2} \, dx = \begin{cases}
a(1 + 2 \ln a) \text{Ei}[(x - 1) \ln a] - \dfrac{2a^x}{x - 1} + C & a > 0, a \neq 1\\[2ex]
\ln |x - 1| - \dfrac{2}{x - 1} + C & a = 1
\end{cases}$$